# Protection against git removal of untracked .gitignored files?

Tags: git

I ask because git stash -u began removing my .gitignored eclipse configuration settings, and didn't save them to the stash. I totally lost my project configuration. (Please let me know if this is not the correct or intended behavior)

What other commands might remove untracked, ignored files?

What are some effective precautionary measures to ensure untracked local files aren't deleted?

**Edit - Supplementary information:**

[**git-stash**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html)

Use --all instead of -u if you want to keep your .gitignored files.

*[-u|--include-untracked]*

> If the --include-untracked option is used, all untracked files are also stashed and then cleaned up with git clean, leaving the working directory in a very clean state. If the --all option is used instead then the ignored files are stashed and cleaned in addition to the untracked files.

Comment: `git stash -u` should stash untracked files (in additional to tracked changes to your working directory). If you restore the stash, your untracked files should be there again. If not, something is wrong.

Comment: @patrickvacek Just tried it again. `git stash` will behave appropriately. `git stash -u` will throw errors "unlink of file" for files that eclipse is currently using, and are in the .gitignore. Closing eclipse and allowing the unlink of files is what got me into trouble.

Comment: A quick local test says untracked files should not be affected (I'm using git v.1.8.1.2). I don't know what went wrong in your case.

Comment: @LeGEC using git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0 (from win git bash installer)

Comment: 1.8.1.msysgit.1 here, same issue, `git stash -u` cleaned ignored files but did not stash them.

Comment: Only some ignored files were affected: specifically, the affected files appeared to be those listed in `.gitignore` in the working tree or index but not listed in `.gitignore` in the HEAD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are some effective precautionary measures to ensure untracked
>   local files aren't deleted?

Don't use commands that delete files :-).

Seriously: There is no specific protection in git for untracked files, but git generally tries very hard not to lose any data unless you explicitly tell it to.

Even most dangerous commands (like `git reset --hard` , `git checkout -- file`) will not touch untracked files. The only dangerous commands are (AFAIK):

- `git stash -u` (as you found out)
- `git clean`

Also, I found that it is best to *never* have valuable data in untracked files. If it's important, it needs to be checked in. Only throwaway data and generated files should be .gitignored.

As to Eclipse configuration: It's probably best to have some tool to autogenerate it (or have Eclipse generate it itself via discovery). Then you can safely .gitignore it, and recreate it if lost.